# How to insert combobox selected item pk into mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, combobox

i'm a new member. I really need your help. :)

Problem: I want to insert selected item of combo box into mysql, but i dont want the item, but i want the pk of selected item to be insert. I need help to detect my error and tell me what is the problem and what should i do. FYI, i'm using netbeans.
Here is my code.

// member type combo box

```
private void FillComboBoxMemberRegistration(){
    try{
        String sql = "select * from jeniskeahlian";
        pst =  conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String memberType = rs.getString("Type");
            MemberTypeComboBox.addItem(memberType);

        }


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

//Member type combo box [Insert]

```
        String memberTypeList = MemberTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String sql1  ="Select MemberTypeID from jeniskeahlian where Type = '" + memberTypeList ;
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            String memberType = rs.getString("MemberTypeID");
            pst.setString(10, memberType);


        }
```

Comment: I don't see where is the INSERT in the second code snippet

Comment: ahh~ i forgot to paste the insert statement

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have forgotten a second apostrophe to close your string at

```
String sql1  ="Select MemberTypeID from jeniskeahlian where Type = '" + memberTypeList ;
```

However, I suggest you to, since you are already using a `PreparedStatement`, do it this way:

```
String sql1  ="Select MemberTypeID from jeniskeahlian where Type = ?" ;
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
pst.setString(1, memberTypeList);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

This way is far more secure (you can't receive an SQL injection attack) and performs better (since your database can reuse the query plan for future queries)

Comment: By the way, I don't understand what are you doing with the `ResultSet` you get as a result of this query; I suggest you think twice about it since any further call to `setString()` over your `PreparedStatement` will do nothing once you have executed the query

Comment: thanks Jorge, i'm still new in object oriented, so i really need advice, Thanks Jorge. :)